# Python 3 for beginners Control Flow, While Loops and Break Statements

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, break, control-flow

I bought a book to teach myself programming using Python.I am not taking any online course at the moment. I'm in chapter 2 and having problems with an exercise. I am to write a program that asks for 10 integers and then prints the largest odd number. If no odd number was entered, it should print a message saying so.

```
x = 0
largest_odd = int() 
while(x < 10):
    user_input = int(input('Enter an integer '))
    if user_input%2 != 0 and user_input > largest_odd:
        largest_odd = user_input
    elif user_input%2 == 0 and x == 10:
        print('no odd numbers')
    x += 1
print(f'the largest odd number is {largest_odd}')
```

I am having a hard time entering all even numbers without printing the last print statement. I understand that the last print statement will print regardless because it is outside of the loop. But I've been on this the past few hours and can't figure out what I should change.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem right you could just put a IF statement after the loop:

```
x = 0
largest_odd = 0

while x < 10:
    user_input = int(input('Enter an integer '))
    
    # check if x is odd and bigger than largest_odd
    if user_input % 2 != 0 and user_input > largest_odd:
        largest_odd = user_input
    
    x += 1

if not largest_odd:
    print('No odd numbers inputed!')
else:
    print('The largest odd number is {}'.format(largest_odd))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm slightly annoyed bc I think I could have figured this out if I would have just walked away from the computer! I appreciate you taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with using the if-statements. What you need to do is to move the verification for if there were no odd numbers outside of the loop itself, and make an else-statement that prints out the largest if that isn't true:

```
x = 1
largest_odd = int()
while(x <= 10):
    user_input = int(input(f'Enter an integer ({x}/10): '))
    if user_input % 2 != 0 and user_input > largest_odd:
        largest_odd = user_input
    x += 1

if largest_odd == 0:
    print('There was no odd numbers.')
else:    
    print(f'The largest odd number is {largest_odd}')
```

Because `int()` will default to `0` if you don't give it an argument, then we can use that as the verification, because `0` is not an even number.

I also changed the values of `x` changed the while-statement into `x <= 10` so that we can make the representation of the input a little bit better.